# Calculating the probability of b not in range of A

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ where elements of $A$ and $b$ are drawn i.i.d from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
I have ran simulations and could not find an instance where $b \in \mathcal{R}(A)$.

---

**Question:**

Is it possible to show that $\mathbb{P}(b \in \mathcal{R}(A)) < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$  may depend on $m$ and $n$?

---

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $m>n$:

Since $A$ has rank at most $n$, the image of $A$ will be at most $n$-dimensional. Since $m>n$, the image of $A$ is a proper lower-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^m$. Now since $b$ is an $m$-dimensional random vector with Lebesgue density (multivariate normal), the probability of $b$ lying in this lower-dimensional subspace $\mathcal R(A)$ is equal to $0$.

Now suppose $m<n$:

$\textbf{Claim: The probability that $A$ has rank $m$ is $1$.}$ 
Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be the columns of $A$. Choose any $k<m$ and suppose $a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}$ are linearly independent. Then in order for $a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},a_k$ to be linearly dependent, we would need $a_k$ to be in the span of $\{a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}\}$. Since the span is a $k-1$-dimensional space and $a_k$ is an $m$-dimensional ($m>k$) random variable with Lebesgue density, the probability of $a_k$ being in any given $k-1$-dimensional subspace is $0$. Hence with probability $1$ the rank of $A$ is maximal, $\text{rank}(A)=m$. Therefore $\mathcal R(A)=\mathbb R^m$ almost-surely and therefore $\mathbb P[b\in \mathcal R(A)]=1$.

I'll leave the case $m=n$ for you to think about.

Comment: I am not very familiar with these kind of proofs but "the probability of $b$
 lying in this lower-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is equal to 0" seems very clear to you. Can you please add its proof to your solution.